# In the Linux Terminal, is there a difference between "bash foo.sh" and "./foo.sh"

Tags: bash, shell-script

When executing a bash script in the Linux Terminal, is there a difference between "`bash foo.sh`" and "`./foo.sh`"?  Or are they just two different ways of performing the same function?

Comment: Assuming the shebang line for `foo.sh` is pointing to `bash` they'd be the same thing, oh, and assuming you have the execute permission on `foo.sh` which is not required for `bash foo.sh` but is for `./foo.sh`

Answer (score 1):

They are likely equivalent if `./foo.sh`

1. is executable, and
2. begins with with `#!/bin/bash` (or equivalent)

Otherwise, and given the precondition you describe (`foo.sh` is a bash script), the `./foo.sh` version may well fail, either because it doesn't have execute permission for the user, or because it is interpreted by `/bin/sh` instead of `/bin/bash` (`/bin/sh` is the default script interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Tobys answer I want to point out that one should check existing shebang bash params in the script (like #!/bin/bash -e) before calling just 'bash foo.sh'. Calling a script via 'bash foo.sh' will not care about existing bash params in the shebang.

Answer (score 0):

People already explained here but in simple words `bash foo.sh` mean foo.sh will be executed in bash shell.

It is just a way to tell the kernel to which shell script  will be use to run the script with making any changes in script.